# Cloud ML prediction off for housing-regression example

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

Running the housing-regression Cloud ML [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/cloudml-template/examples/housing-regression). I was unable to predict a reasonable value.

I was able to run a prediction task in the cloud via

`gcloud ml-engine predict
    --model=${MODEL_NAME}
    --version=${MODEL_VERSION}
    --json-instances=data/new-data.json`
where `new-data.json` is the default json file.

However, the prediction yields a value of

`PREDICTIONS
[5.268091678619385]`

which is weird because the correct MEDV value for this data (first row of train-data-01.csv) is `34.7`.

I tried again with different test data and with a completely different data set and never did the prediction yield something reasonable.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Here we face a deep Learning scenario which is totally different from Statistical regression approaches. There are 13 different features and MEDV based on a feature does not work. If you use a neural network with only one layer without activation function you may end up with a linear combination of MEDVs of features. Even if you find the optimal weights of the linear combination of the MEDVs it is much less than the 34.7. 
However, taking into the account the activation function of each neural network layer and depending on the number of layers, hyper-parameter tuning, and the number of evaluation steps the result is different. Prediction 5.268091678619385 is most likely correct.
 Thus, the predicted value of the Deep Learning module can be totally different from the Expected value of MEDVs.

Comment: How do you mean the prediction is correct? It is far from the real value. And if so, how do I interpret this value then?

Comment: I ended up with the same result. So, there are two possibilities: 1- Outlier data point  2- Under-fitting. I Increased the train-steps to 1000 and came up with the some error. Thus, in this case, the data is outlier  and also the volume of data is not enough to train the neural network well enough.